# cross-correlation using ccf in R

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, cross-correlation

I wanted to use ccf in R to compute the cross-correlation on two sets of time-series data. My question is how can I know if any of the correlation coefficients in the plot falls outside the dash blue lines without manually looking at it? Since I have tens of thousands sets of time-series data to deal with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You asking question about `R` but you don't add it as a tag? Since you add _c#_, _java_, _php_, _javascript_? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I changed your tags for you since you had none of the relevant tags for your post. Take the advice of @SonerGönül and read how to properly post.

Comment: You know that if you use the confidence interval as a kind of test statistic you will probably suffer alpha error inflation (repeated testing)?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way to calculate the confidence intervals:

```
res <- ccf(mdeaths, fdeaths, ylab = "cross-correlation")

upperCI <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(res$n.used)
lowerCI <- -qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(res$n.used)
```

However, `help(plot.acf)` warns:

> The confidence interval plotted in plot.acf is based on an
>   uncorrelated series and should be treated with appropriate caution.
>   Using ci.type = "ma" may be less potentially misleading.

Look at `getAnywhere(plot.acf)` to learn how to calculate confidence intervals of type "ma".

Comment: and then `any(res$acf>upperCI | res$acf<lowerCI)`