# how to manually calculate ci.type='ma' in ccf()

Tags: r, cross-correlation

I have been trying to calculate the confidence interval for ci.type='ma' manually.   I read a related post ([cross-correlation using ccf in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551209/cross-correlation-using-ccf-in-r)) which was helpful but I am getting hung up on the details of

```
getAnywhere(plot.acf)
```

So far I have:

```
x <- ccf(x=x,y=y,ci.type='ma')

clim0 <- qnorm((1+0.95)/2)/sqrt(x$n.used) # upper CI when ci.type=NULL
clim <- clim0 + * sqrt(cumsum(c(1, 2 * x$acf[-1, 
                                               i, i]^2)))  # from getAnywhere(plot.acf)
```

But I don't understand how i is defined in the function details.  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: `confint` function might be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `getAnywhere(plot.acf)`, i is iterated from 1 through the length of your series:

```
for (i in 1L:nser) {
                clim <- clim0 * sqrt(cumsum(c(1, 2 * x$acf[-1, 
                  i, i]^2)))
                ylim <- range(c(-clim, clim, ylim))
            }
```

however, in the acf function you can specify 'ma' for the ci with `ci.type='ma'`
see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html