# How to calculate confidence intervals for each bar plotted from CCF function to see if they are significantly different from other bars in R

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

I've researched how to identify what the Confidence Intervals are for a given bar to be considered statistically significant, [cross-correlation using ccf in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551209/cross-correlation-using-ccf-in-r) when using the CCF() function.  However, I'm trying to make comparisons across lag bars that are statistically significant to see if they are significantly different from other bars.  Is there a way to calculate the confidence interval of the ACF correlation found for each bar on a CCF plot?

The code below simulates some data that illustrates the issue.  You can see that there are 4 bars (lags -3 to 1) that are all significant at the .9999 confidence level.

What I am trying to determine if the ACF correlation at lag -1 is significantly different from the coefficients observed at lags -2 and 0. I believe calculating the CIs for each bar would allow me to do this, but I am unsure how to achieve this.

```
#Simulating 2 time seres that are correlated across multiple lags
set.seed(1)
y <- filter(rnorm(1000), filter=rep(1,3), circular=TRUE)
#plot(y)
x = lag(y, 1) * 2
#plot(x)
ccfObject = ccf(x,y, 3)
plot(ccfObject, ci=.9999)
```

[image: CCF output]

**My Official Question**

1. How can I calculate the confidence interval for each bar outputted by the CCF() function in R?

Secondarily...
 2. Is making this type of comparison statistically valid?  If not, how should I make such comparisions in R?

Comment: (1/2) It's borderline, but this is really more of a question about statistics (or interpretation of output of statistical software) than a programming question; I'm voting to close/migrate to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) ... if you can figure out a good expression for the confidence intervals of the sample CCF, implementing it in R should be relatively easy (and you can come back and ask another question on SO ...) Also, I think the statistical issues are sufficiently problematic that you should sort them out on CV first.

Comment: (2) This has come up on the R help list (without a useful answer) in the past ... https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/112373.html

Comment: There's an expression in http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2737418/ that might be helpful, but I haven't looked too closely at it